# ¿Como contar el numero de ocurrencias de una palabra dentro de una frase sin importar el orden de las letras?

Tags: java, algoritmos

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String palabra1, palabra2;
    int contador = 0;

    System.out.println("Escriba una frase");
    palabra1 = sc.nextLine();
    palabra1 = palabra1.toLowerCase();
    System.out.println("Escriba una palabra");
    palabra2 = sc.nextLine();
    palabra2 = palabra2.toLowerCase();

    while (palabra1.contains(palabra2)) {
        palabra1 = palabra1.substring(palabra1.indexOf(
                palabra2) + palabra2.length(), palabra1.length());
        contador++;
    }

    System.out.println(contador);
}
```

Que puedo hacer para que el algoritmo, me cuente las veces que aparece la palabra2 en la palabra1 sin importar el orden de las letras de la palabra2.

Ejemplo:
palabra1: Hola, muy buena ola Laomir!
palabra2: oal
Resultado: 3

Comment: Podrías pasar a array de caracteres "palabra2" e ir cambiando el orden en el array de alguna manera. Si no, podrías ir cogiendo de 0 al tamaño de palabra1, el número de caracteres que tiene "palabra2" y compararlo. Si todas las letras están, entonces hay ocurrencia, si no, seguimos. Para el segundo método ten en cuenta que si tienes "Patito" y "palabra2" contiene 3 caracteres deberás coger "pat" "ati" "tit" "ito"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posible solucion es la siguiente:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {   
  ...//todo igual hasta el while y el while se remplaza con lo que sigue
  List<Character> charsPalabra2 = stringToList(palabra2);//creamos una lista de
                                                         //char a partir de parabra2
  for(char ch : palabra1.toCharArray()){//recorremos los char que componen palabra1
    Character c = Character.valueOf(ch);
    if(charsPalabra2.contains(c)){//si la lista de letras que faltan para reconocer 
                                  //una permutacion de palabra 2 contiene la 
                                  //c letra de la palabra 1 sacamos una ocurrencia de 
                                  //de la lista
      charsPalabra2.remove(c);
      if(charsPalabra2.isEmpty()){//si despues de eso quedo vacia entoces se 
                                  //reconocio una permutacion de la palabra2 entera 
                                  //por lo cual se suma 1 al contador y se reinicia             
                                  //charsPalabra2 para seguir buscando la palabra         
                                  //completa 
        charsPalabra2 = stringToList(palabra2); 
        contador++;
      }
    }else{//si no contiene entonces se reinicia  para buscar la palabra completa 
      charsPalabra2 = stringToList(palabra2);
    }
  }
  System.out.println(contador);
}

//funcion usada para pasar de String s a una List<Character> compuesta de los //caracteres de s
static List<Character> stringToList(String s){
  List<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
  for(char c : s.toCharArray()) {
    list.add(c);
  }
  return list;
}
```

Dejo también una explicación mas abstracta del algoritmo:

El algoritmo  consiste en primero tener una lista de todas las letras (repeticiones incluidas) de la palabra2 que deben ser encoradas en la cadena de forma contigua para reconocer una ocurrencia para simplificar vamos a llamar a esta lista charsPalabra2.

Después se debe ir recorriendo las letras (caracteres) de palabra1 y cada vez que se encuentra una letra que esta en charsPalabra2 esta se quita de dicha lista ya que se acaba de reconocer, a continuación si se reconoce otra letra de charsPalabra2 esta también se quita y así sucesivamente hasta que la  charsPalabra2 queda vaciá lo que significa que reconocimos la palabra2 correctamente esto lleva a dos observaciones:

1. Al estar revisando si la letra de palabra1 se encuentra en charsPalabra2 no se esta teniendo en cuenta el orden dentro de charsPalabra2 por lo que se esta cumpliendo con dicho requerimiento de que no importa el orden.
2. No necesariamente una vez que se reconoce una letra de palabra1 en charsPalabra2 se tiene que seguir reconociendo a las demás por esto cuando sucede que se llega a una letra que no esta en charsPalabra2 entonces se reinicia charsPalabra2 de forma de que todas las letras que se quitaron por ser reconocidas vuelvan a estar a en la lista ya que necesitan ser reconocidas nuevamente para que el algoritmo funcione de forma correcta.

Answer (score 1):

Acá te dejo una implementación hecha con javascript:

```js
var palabra1 = 'Hola, muy buena ola laomir';
var palabra2 = 'oal';

function encontrarPalabra(palabra1,palabra2){
  //variable para contar las veces que se encontró la palabra
 var encontradas = 0;
  //recorriendo toda la cadena de palabra2
 for(var x = 0; x < palabra2.length; x++){
   //se obtiene la letra por al cual vamos a pivotear
    var primeraLetraBusqueda = palabra2[x];
    //se divide la longitud de la cadena a buscar tomando solo la parte positiva para saber cuantos caracteres obtener tanto anteriores como posteriores de nuestro punto de pivote.
    var longitudABuscar = Math.trunc(palabra2.length / 2);
    // se recorre la cadena principal buscando el caracter de pivote
    for(var i = 0; i < palabra1.length ; i++){
    //si encontramos el caracter de pivote en la posición 2 de la cadena princial (o sea en el caracter l de Hola) entonces tomamos los caracteres anteriores y posteriores que nos indica "longitudABuscar"
      if(palabra1[i] === primeraLetraBusqueda){
        var cadenaAnteriorPosterior = palabra1.substring(i - longitudABuscar, (i + longitudABuscar) + 1);
        //obtenida la cadena desde el caracter de pivote vemos si los caracteres de la misma se encuentran en la cadena a buscar
        if(cadenaEncontrada(cadenaAnteriorPosterior,palabra2))
          encontradas++;
      }
    }
 }
  
  return encontradas;
}

function cadenaEncontrada(cadenaABuscar,cadena){
  var encontradas = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < cadenaABuscar.length ; i++)
     if(cadena.indexOf(cadenaABuscar[i])>=0)
       encontradas++;
    return encontradas == cadena.length;
}

document.getElementById("cuenta").innerHTML = encontrarPalabra(palabra1,palabra2);
```

```html
<pre id="cuenta">

</pre>
```

Describo el paso a paso de la función:

Se busca un caracter de la palabra2 en palabra1

Si se encuentra entonces se toma como punto de referencia para buscar la cadena a buscar (palabra2)

La cadena a buscar en el ejemplo tiene una longitud de 3 caracteres, entonces a partir de donde se encontró el caracter de la palabra2 en palabra1 se completa la cadena a buscar teniendo en cuenta que se tomará el número de caracteres que indique la división del longitud de palabra2 entre 2, ejemplo:

> Suponiendo que estamos en el caracter **l** de palabra2, tenemos que ese
>   caracter se encuentra en la posición 2 de la cadena palabra1,
>   palabra2.length es 3 por lo que la division entera es 1, tomamos un
>   caracter antes y un caracter después a la posición antes mencionada,
>   quedando la cadena ola.

Al encontrar la cadena a buscar se hace uso de la función "cadenaEncontrada" que indicará true si todos los caracteres de la cadena a buscar se encuentran en la cadena palabra2.

Si la función retorna true entonces se incrementa el contados de veces que se encontró la cadena.